# My High School's Reunion

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, optimization

My high school is celebrating 30 years since graduating its first class and is planning to invite for lunch 20 alumni, 600 in all, from each of those classes.

Hosts are planning to sit everyone in tables with the same number of alumni. They also wish to make sure that for any two classes, say years X and Y, at least one student from each of those two classes sit together in at least one of the tables.

For social distancing purposes, it is also desired to sit as few alumni as possible in each table.

How few can that be?

Comment: A lower bound of $3$ is easy to prove and I believe it's the answer. The remaining problem is the following: given $30$ people, each day we divide them into $10$ groups of three, is it possible that within $20$ days any two people has been put into the same group at least for one day? I believe the answer is "yes" but didn't find a simple construction.

Comment: Here's an algorithm for Steiner Triple Systems: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72084/constructing-steiner-triple-systems-algorithmically

Comment: That doesn't entirely solve it though, given the other constraints...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the number of people per table is $p$, then to cover each pair we must have $$\frac{600}{p} \binom{p}{2} \ge \binom{30}{2},$$ which implies that $p \ge \lceil 49/20 \rceil = 3$.  The following set of $200$ triples of years covers every pair and contains each year exactly $20$ times:

```
{{1,2,22},{1,3,5},{1,3,7},{1,4,20},{1,6,8},{1,7,15},{1,9,10},{1,11,12},{1,11,22},{1,12,13},{1,12,
21},{1,14,17},{1,14,18},{1,14,19},{1,16,18},{1,23,25},{1,24,29},{1,25,28},{1,26,29},{1,27,30},{2,3
,15},{2,4,23},{2,5,20},{2,6,26},{2,7,24},{2,7,25},{2,7,27},{2,7,30},{2,8,29},{2,9,28},{2,10,28},{2
,11,25},{2,11,28},{2,12,23},{2,13,24},{2,14,30},{2,15,18},{2,16,21},{2,17,19},{3,4,13},{3,6,28},{3
,8,28},{3,9,21},{3,10,18},{3,11,29},{3,12,20},{3,12,25},{3,14,15},{3,14,28},{3,15,16},{3,17,23},{3
,19,20},{3,22,30},{3,24,28},{3,26,28},{3,27,29},{4,5,23},{4,6,13},{4,6,17},{4,7,21},{4,8,13},{4,9,
25},{4,10,29},{4,11,27},{4,12,14},{4,15,16},{4,18,25},{4,18,29},{4,19,23},{4,21,22},{4,21,30},{4,
24,26},{4,28,30},{5,6,12},{5,7,10},{5,8,15},{5,8,16},{5,9,20},{5,10,20},{5,11,21},{5,13,28},{5,14,
25},{5,15,21},{5,15,27},{5,16,22},{5,16,27},{5,17,18},{5,19,30},{5,21,26},{5,24,29},{6,7,22},{6,9,
16},{6,10,15},{6,10,26},{6,10,29},{6,11,30},{6,14,23},{6,14,27},{6,16,25},{6,18,27},{6,19,23},{6,
20,26},{6,21,23},{6,24,25},{7,8,28},{7,9,10},{7,9,30},{7,11,21},{7,12,23},{7,13,29},{7,14,22},{7,
15,20},{7,16,17},{7,18,19},{7,22,26},{8,9,25},{8,10,12},{8,11,19},{8,11,21},{8,12,24},{8,14,24},{8
,15,19},{8,16,26},{8,17,25},{8,18,20},{8,18,30},{8,22,24},{8,23,27},{9,11,17},{9,12,15},{9,13,15},
{9,13,27},{9,14,21},{9,17,30},{9,18,22},{9,19,27},{9,20,26},{9,23,29},{9,24,26},{10,11,25},{10,12,
14},{10,13,14},{10,13,22},{10,16,30},{10,17,21},{10,18,24},{10,19,27},{10,23,29},{11,13,27},{11,14
,23},{11,15,23},{11,16,18},{11,20,30},{11,24,30},{11,26,27},{12,14,18},{12,14,26},{12,16,22},{12,
16,29},{12,17,30},{12,19,20},{12,27,28},{13,15,22},{13,16,18},{13,17,27},{13,19,20},{13,19,26},{13
,21,27},{13,23,30},{13,25,30},{14,16,20},{14,19,29},{15,17,25},{15,21,24},{15,26,30},{15,28,29},{
16,17,24},{16,19,28},{16,22,23},{17,18,21},{17,20,21},{17,20,24},{17,22,30},{17,23,28},{17,26,29},
{18,23,24},{18,24,29},{18,26,28},{19,21,28},{19,22,28},{19,24,25},{19,24,27},{20,22,28},{20,23,26}
,{20,25,27},{20,26,29},{21,25,29},{22,25,26},{22,25,27},{22,29,30}}
```

The pair $\{3,28\}$ appears $5$ times.  For a more balanced coverage, with each pair appearing at most twice, use:

```
{{1,2,3},{1,3,6},{1,4,5},{1,4,17},{1,5,26},{1,6,7},{1,8,9},{1,9,18},{1,10,11},{1,12,13},{1,14,15},
{1,16,24},{1,16,30},{1,17,21},{1,18,24},{1,19,27},{1,20,26},{1,22,25},{1,23,29},{1,28,30},{2,4,6},
{2,5,7},{2,5,23},{2,7,27},{2,8,10},{2,8,17},{2,9,11},{2,10,22},{2,12,22},{2,13,15},{2,14,24},{2,15
,19},{2,16,20},{2,16,28},{2,18,25},{2,21,27},{2,23,26},{2,24,28},{2,29,30},{3,4,7},{3,5,19},{3,5,
21},{3,8,11},{3,9,10},{3,12,15},{3,12,26},{3,13,14},{3,13,29},{3,16,23},{3,17,22},{3,18,20},{3,18,
23},{3,19,30},{3,20,28},{3,24,26},{3,25,27},{3,25,30},{4,6,24},{4,8,12},{4,9,13},{4,10,14},{4,11,
16},{4,11,21},{4,12,30},{4,13,26},{4,15,21},{4,18,27},{4,19,26},{4,20,22},{4,20,25},{4,22,28},{4,
23,27},{4,23,29},{5,6,25},{5,7,20},{5,8,13},{5,9,12},{5,9,24},{5,10,15},{5,11,14},{5,11,22},{5,16,
27},{5,17,20},{5,18,30},{5,21,29},{5,23,28},{5,27,28},{6,8,24},{6,9,15},{6,10,12},{6,11,13},{6,13,
21},{6,14,21},{6,15,27},{6,16,17},{6,17,23},{6,18,19},{6,19,22},{6,20,29},{6,22,30},{6,26,27},{6,
28,30},{7,8,21},{7,9,14},{7,10,13},{7,11,23},{7,12,28},{7,15,18},{7,15,24},{7,16,25},{7,16,30},{7,
17,26},{7,18,28},{7,19,30},{7,20,23},{7,22,27},{7,24,29},{8,9,29},{8,10,26},{8,13,22},{8,14,20},{8
,15,25},{8,15,28},{8,16,19},{8,17,23},{8,18,21},{8,18,29},{8,24,25},{8,27,30},{9,10,30},{9,14,24},
{9,15,28},{9,16,26},{9,17,19},{9,20,22},{9,21,23},{9,21,25},{9,22,29},{9,27,28},{10,11,25},{10,13,
24},{10,16,29},{10,17,20},{10,17,27},{10,18,22},{10,19,29},{10,21,26},{10,21,28},{10,23,25},{11,12
,20},{11,12,27},{11,15,26},{11,16,18},{11,17,27},{11,19,23},{11,19,28},{11,20,30},{11,24,25},{11,
26,29},{12,14,23},{12,16,21},{12,17,28},{12,18,26},{12,19,24},{12,21,30},{12,22,29},{12,24,27},{12
,25,29},{13,16,17},{13,17,25},{13,18,23},{13,19,21},{13,19,26},{13,20,27},{13,25,28},{13,29,30},{
14,15,19},{14,16,18},{14,16,27},{14,17,29},{14,18,25},{14,19,25},{14,20,21},{14,22,30},{14,26,28},
{14,28,29},{15,16,22},{15,16,23},{15,17,30},{15,20,25},{15,27,29},{17,18,24},{17,18,29},{19,20,24}
,{19,20,28},{21,22,24},{21,22,26},{22,23,26},{23,24,30},{25,26,30}}
```

Comment: Can you sketch the algorithm you used to generate this?

Comment: I used integer linear programming, with a binary decision variable for each of the $\binom{30}{3}=4060$ possible triples, a linear $\ge 1$ constraint for each pair, and a linear $=20$ constraint for each year.

Comment: @RobPratt I wonder: What are the fewest and most alumni the school can invite from each of the classes (the same number from each class) so that 3 remains the least number that can be fitted in a single table. And are all values in between possible?

Comment: Let $k$ be the number per class.  Then we must have $\frac{30k}{p}\binom{p}{2} \ge \binom{30}{2}$, equivalently, $k(p-1) \ge 29$, so $k<29 \implies p \ge 3$.  Also, $p=3$ implies $k \ge 15$.  It turns out that all $k\in\{15,\dots,28\}$ yield a minimum of $3$ per table.  For $k=29$, the minimum per table is $2$ (one table for each pair of years).